# Bootstrap 4 Cards in Columns Overlapping

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am making a product display page using Bootstrap 4. In full size the columns are displayed alright but when these columns overlaps each other when displayed in any mobile size screen. I have tried many things including changing the `display` to `inline-block`.

The code is mentioned below please help me!..

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- row 2-->
  <div class="row border ">
    <!--Col 1-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card mh-100 " style="width: 18rem; height: 31rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top " style="" src="C:\Users\acer\OneDrive\Desktop\sufi.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo"></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lets Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-5">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col 2-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card mh-100" style="width: 18rem;height: 31rem">
        <img class="card-img-top " src="C:\Users\acer\OneDrive\Desktop\ear buds.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">IPhone X</h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-5">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col 3-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card mh-100" style="width: 18rem;height: 31rem">
        <img class="card-img-top" style="height:15 rem" src="C:\Users\acer\OneDrive\Desktop\bottle.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Leather Hand Bag </h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo "></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-5">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col-4-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card mh-100" style="width: 18rem;height: 31rem">
        <img class="card-img-top" style="height:15 rem" src="C:\Users\acer\OneDrive\Desktop\bottle.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Leather Hand Bag </h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo "></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-5">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Row-3-->
  <div class="row border topM">
    <!--Col1-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
      <div class="card mh-100" style="width: 18rem;height: 31rem">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="C:\Users\acer\OneDrive\Desktop\sufi.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo"></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-5">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col 2-->
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="card mh-100" style="width: 18rem;height: 31rem">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="C:\Users\acer\OneDrive\Desktop\ear buds.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">IPhone X</h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo"></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-5">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col 3-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
      <div class="card mh-100" style="width: 18rem;height: 31rem">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="C:\Users\acer\OneDrive\Desktop\bottle.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Leather Hand Bag </h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo">Time:</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lets Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-5">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col-4-->
    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
      <div class="card mh-100" style="width: 18rem;height: 31rem">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="C:\Users\acer\OneDrive\Desktop\bottle.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Leather Hand Bag </h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo">Time:</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lets Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-5">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use fixed width like `width: 18rem;` inside of `col-x` elements, it may tear the parent.
2. You have several mistakes like `style="height:15 rem"`. The space between `15` and `rem` will cause the error and this setting will be ignored.
3. I have added to your cols `col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6` so ti  will be more responsive during the screen resizing. More about [bootstrap grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)
4. Bootstrap padding classes like `ml-5` can be used with breakpoints, like `ml-md-5 ml-2` to improve it's view on responsiveness. More about [bootstrap spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <!-- row 2-->
  <div class="row border">
    <!--Col 1-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="card mh-100">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <hr>
          <p><b>Price:</b>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo"></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lets Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-md-5 ml-2">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col 2-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="card mh-100">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">IPhone X</h5>
          <hr>
          <p><b>Price:</b>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-md-5 ml-2">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col 3-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="card mh-100">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Leather Hand Bag </h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo "></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-md-5 ml-2">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col-4-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="card mh-100">
        <img class="card-img-top" style="height:15 rem" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Leather Hand Bag </h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo "></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-md-5 ml-2">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Row-3-->
  <div class="row border topM">
    <!--Col1-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="card mh-100">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo"></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-md-5 ml-2">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col 2-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="card mh-100">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">IPhone X</h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo"></p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-md-5 ml-2">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col 3-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="card mh-100">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Leather Hand Bag </h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo">Time:</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lets Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-md-5 ml-2">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--Col-4-->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-2">
      <div class="card mh-100">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Leather Hand Bag </h5>
          <hr>
          <p><span style="font-weight:bold ;">Price:</span>200Rs</p>
          <p class="card-text demo">Time:</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lets Bid</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success ml-md-5 ml-2">Buy Now!</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```